# How can I write the equivalent dynamically-allocated nested Vectors from C++ to Obj-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, porting

We're porting over some C++ .h to Objective C .h files.

Here is a sample of the C++ code we're trying to port over for our class.

```
    std::vector< std::vector< int > > D2DMap;
    std::vector< std::vector< int > > D3DMap;
```

We have yet to be successful in declaring an equivalent in Obj-C.

```
    NSMutableArray *D2DMap = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *inner = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [inner addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someInt]];
    [D2DMap addObject:inner];
```

But we know this is wrong because it is not dynamic at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Objective-C++.

If you don't want to use Objective-C++, you're sort of out of luck. There is no non-dynamically-typed array in the Cocoa library. You could hack together a solution involving malloc and other generally disgusting things, but I'd recommend against it.

Comment: You can have statically typed Cocoa collections: http://www.jonmsterling.com/posts/2012-02-05-typed-collections-with-self-types-in-objective-c.html . I'd make that an answer, but not clear to me that that's what's being asked here.